# Web-scraping: some data (image) seems unavailable for scraping?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get image URL from a web-site using Python, Selenium and Firefox however seems I face the case when it is not possible? There is not  element but image is displayed. When I use 'inspect' in Firefox it suggests the following element for image however I can't see anything about image source in it:

```
<canvas width="575" height="575" id="orbitvu-2154214-obj-canvas" class="orbitvu-viewer-object-canvas zindexer" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 1;"></canvas>
```

Also I can see that firefox downloads the image when downloading the web-site and the image download is triggered by a js script embedded in the site. So I assume this script is doing some magic here - it downloads images and somehow makes browsers dispaying it while there is nothing in the final HTML source that can be used to identify image source location. 
I wonder if there are cases when it is simply not possible to scrape the date and maybe this is one of them?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an image, that is a canvas element. Canvas is used for drawing graphics on a web page, you can draw images onto canvas though which is likely where your confusion is coming from. It is likely the image is streamed down and then JavaScript draws it onto the canvas, look in their JavaScript source code to find out more, or link us the url so we can look

Comment: I think it is the following script that draws image on that canvas: https://www.scorett.se//M1/stage/scripts/orbit/orbitvu.js It is a bit weird that result of script execution is not reflected in the final HTML I am taking from browser?

Comment: Something like `document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();` should allow you to then download the whole canvas as an image.

Comment: But why image data is not present in canvas when I look in 'view page source'? Probably I am missing something fundamental here (I am far from web development) but am I wrong expecting to see everything in source code after all scripts executed?

Comment: Image data is present in the canvas, you won't see it in page source though as it is drawn on with javascript

Comment: I thought browser runs javascript and javascript produces html ultimately? Besides, when I right click on the picture, I can download the image but why I can't find its URL in the page source? Somehow browser knows image URL without executing javascript?

Comment: Because its url isn't in the page source which is what I'm telling you, it's drawn on with javascript. You'll need to do some research on how canvas works in detail